# Why screenshot of a view captured in layoutsubviews/viewdidlayoutsubviews is not what rendered in the screen at last?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I have a view with **autolayout**, and need to be taken screenshot. And I found the screenshot is messed up with layouts, however the real object rendered in screen is totally correct. So I put the code everywhere to find out where I can got the correct screenshot with correct layout.

I tried `layoutsubviews` `viewdidlayoutsubviews` and failed.

So, is there any method that can tell me that the specific view is totally and correctly layout and it will **not change** after being rendered in screen?

ps: the more I use autolayout, the more I feel tired with it

Comment: First idea is `viewWillAppear` & `viewDidAppear`, but you probably tried that already. Hard to help without seeing code.

Answer (score 0):

Take screenshot in viewdidappear method.